# NSXML parsing in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-scraping, nsxmlparser

I don't fully get when I would implement the parser didStartElement delegate method versus the didEndElement delegate method. My code managed to extract what I want (the title) from a url being used, but I don't know if I should be implementing my code and using the didStartElement delegate method to process the data I'm getting.

```
#import "ClassB.h"

@implementation ClassB

-(id)loadHTMLWithURL:(NSString *)urlString {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    self.nodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    self.elementArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.parse = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];
    self.parse.delegate = self;
    self.classA = [ClassA new];
    [self.parse parse];
    return self;
}

//-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
// 
//    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
//        self.classA.tag = elementName;
//        self.classA.value = self.nodeContent;
//    }
//    
//    
//}
//
//


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {

        self.classA.tag = elementName;
        self.classA.value = self.nodeContent;
        [self.elementArray addObject:self.classA];

    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    self.nodeContent = (NSMutableString *)[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}    

@end
```

ClassA is just a separate class I'm using to store a tag string (title, which is what I'm looking for) and the value of that tag.

Comment: None of the code you posted populates `nodeContent`. What is it supposed to have in it?

Comment: code edited to include the piece that I forgot to add to my post.